# unable to implement waffle authentication, using tomcat on linux. javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat7, waffle

i am using tomcat on linux, trying to authenticate users using waffle.

my META_INF/context.xml is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
     appName="Jaas"
     userClassNames="waffle.jaas.UserPrincipal"
     roleClassNames="waffle.jaas.RolePrincipal"
     useContextClassLoader="false"
     debug="true" />
</Context>
```

my error code is

```
Login exception authenticating username "amahajan"
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'Advapi32': libAdvapi32.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)
        at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:142)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
        at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32.<clinit>(Advapi32.java:40)
        at waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.logonDomainUserEx(Unknown Source)
        at waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.logonDomainUser(Unknown Source)
        at waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsAuthProviderImpl.logonUser(Unknown Source)
        at waffle.jaas.WindowsLoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:573)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:886)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:698)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:696)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:695)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm.authenticate(JAASRealm.java:354)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:573)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

my login.conf is

```
Jaas {
    waffle.jaas.WindowsLoginModule sufficient debug=false;
};
```

in my web.xml i gave

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  <realm-name>Jaas</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
  <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>Waffle Security Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Protected Area</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>Everyone</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

i think the error is how i start up tomcat and use it, i dont have any .policy file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after long research i found out waffle doesn't work on any *nix systems.

Comment: that's true .. m also facing the same issue. but can we use kerberos to get implemented for Linux ?